# Receive error to getsize image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to upload and image but I recieve an error in `getclientsize`.

I've tried looking for a solution in google. I've following advice and adjusted my `php.ini` file the `post_max_size` and uploaded_max_size` file however it is still not working for me.

Can anyone can help to solve this issue? Below I've attached the code.

I changed the `upload_max_file` size in `php.ini` but it is still not working. Whatever image I upload is being saved as a `tmp` file in my folder.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\file;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class testing extends Controller
{
    /
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new file;
        $user->title = Input::get('name');
        if(Input::hasFile('image')){
            $file=Input::file('image');
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $file);
            $user->name=$file->getClientoriginalName();
            $user->size=$file->getClientsize();
            $user->type=$file->getClientMimeType();
        }
        $user->save();
        return "data saved";
    }
```

Form:

```
<?php
         echo Form::open(array('url' => '/store','files'=>'true'));
         echo 'Select the file to upload.';
         echo Form::file('image');
         echo Form::text('name');
         echo Form::submit('Upload File');
         echo Form::close();
      ?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting please?

Comment: it shows :SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\php4419.tmp.. I cannot understand why it still work like that although i change the php.ini upload_max_file :(...it store on my upload folder us tmp file

Comment: WHat version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: i am using 5.7 laravel

Comment: did u find a solution to this?